# How to plot fixed effects models in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I ran a fixed effect model which gave out three fixed effects as output. I used plm function and used the following code:

```
m1 <- plm(Y~X, data= panel2, model="within" , index="Unit")
```

now I want to plot these three different lines along with the data points, preferably with different colors foe each fixed effect.

I tried this for plotting the points:

```
panel2$color <- ifelse(panel2$Unit=="a",'red',ifelse(panel2$Unit=="b",'green','blue'))
plot(X,Y,col=panel2$color, pch=19)
```

Now this is giving me colored points, how do I add three fixed effects regression lines to it?